# Entity Framework 6 Command Tree Interceptors for SELECT query

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, interceptor

I implemented base Audit class and inherit other classes from it.

```
public abstract class Audit
{
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    ...
}
public class Batch : Audit
{
    ...
}
```

I want to use some base EF approach to prevent select Audit fields from database. I use Audit fields only for analyse and I don't want read it for my application. To write context.Select in each query is a bad and not general variant.

I found some information about IDbCommandTreeInterceptor. How can i exclude CreatedDate and CreatedBy fields from **select-only** queries on Interceptor side?

How to select Batches without Audit fields without implicit specify on each context query?

Comment: Or maybe ideas how to Map Audit fields as 'Unreadable'?